# USDZ Safari Permissions

Tags: ios, arkit, ios12, usdz

If I spend a lot of time building out a complex and beautiful 3d object for use with ARkit, then embed that object into a webpage using the USDZ format, how do I prevent the unauthorized use of that 3d object via saving or sharing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This file format is not made for protection. The files inside the usdz (zip) are just images and the usdc file [which can be converted back to ASCII](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/Converting-Between-Layer-Formats.html#ConvertingBetweenLayerFormats-Convertingbetween.usdaand.usdcFiles). If you want something like protection in a web browser you can consider obfuscation but this can always be defeated. You should properly copyright your work and if you feel it is necessary, pursue those who use your work without authorisation in the courts.

A USDZ file is supposed to be treated like any image (and most media) encountered on the web. These are generally always shareable and rightsholders are free to pursue unauthorised use but I think they realise the harm that would come from doing so ([imagine if every meme GIF was pursued](https://www.thedailybeast.com/europe-wants-to-ban-you-from-uploading-your-favorite-meme)).